# Can't fix JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I have a json file which contains the following content:

```
#create test.json and add content
dbutils.fs.put("test.json",'{"type": "abc","project_id": "abc","private_key_id": "123","private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCJ05O/Ke3tGA96\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n","client_email": "abc@gmail.com","client_id": "345","auth_uri": "https://accounts.abc.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri": "https://abc","auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://abc","client_x509_cert_url": "https://abcrobot/v1/metadata/x509"}'

#Read test.json
json.loads(test.json)

#Error
JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using `json.loads` method incorrectly. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp)  `with open('test.json','r') as json_file:
    json.loads(json_file)`

Comment: It seems that you miss a `"` after `-----END PRIVATE`, it should be  `'{"private_key": "--END PRIVATE" }'` rather than `'{"private_key": "--END PRIVATE}'`

Comment: @P3qiUB the missing " was due to my copy and paste mistake but the actual script has the right quotation. Thus, your advice did not work.

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid; create a dictionary and use `json.dumps` to generate it.

Comment: The problem is that Python is treating the `\n` as a literal newline, which cannot appear in JSON.

Comment: @chepner How would I solve this? Can you guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't generate JSON by hand; let `json.dumps` do it for you. This will ensure that the newlines appearing in the private key are properly encoded.

```
config = {
    "type": "abc",
    "id": "t1-2-3",
    "private_key_id": "123",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwkO/V+WyyrmTFVFoDN9sN1+AL+KX/IB3y\nZqLJVPGCdQ1l+TlZXbFKFYMwo/Ca4N8g4sy7ZH/9UcqKTxawyqrh7dPcRWWI\nyvAWaEJVCtZhw+Hp4fkmWdoi\n-----END PRIVATE"
}

dbutils.fs.put("test.json", json.dumps(config))

with open("test.json") as f:
    config2 = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

When this happens an easy way to find out what is wrong is to use a JSON validator like for example [this one](https://jsonlint.com/).

in this case you are missing a `"` and the end of your string, this is the correct way:

```
dbutils.fs.put("test.json",'{"type": "abc","id": "t1-2-3","private_key_id":"123","private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwkO/V+WyyrmTFVFoDN9sN1+AL+KX/IB3y\nZqLJVPGCdQ1l+TlZXbFKFYMwo/Ca4N8g4sy7ZH/9UcqKTxawyqrh7dPcRWWI\nyvAWaEJVCtZhw+Hp4fkmWdoi\n-----END PRIVATE" }'
```

Comment: I used this tool, thanks for that. However, even when fixing the issues, the same error remains. Why/